# Как организовать выход из цикла, если в потоке будут только пробельные символы?

Tags: c, c++

Есть такая программа:

```
string n;
while (cin >> n) {
    cout << n;
}
```

Необходимо считывать поток (все, кроме пробельных символов) и выводить на экран. Как организовать выход из цикла, если в потоке будут только пробельные символы?

Comment: @Jek_Rock, на Хэшкоде для форматирования используется только Markdown, поэтому код надо отбивать четырьмя пробелами в начале строки. То, что в редакторе нормально отображается HTML-форматирование - это баг редактора.

Comment: @Etki
А чем обусловлено количество пробелов? Почему 4,а не, например, 2?

Comment: @Etki: Фантазией разработчиков [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)? Думаю, что их вдохновлял самый популярный размер мягкой табуляции (ну или отступа вложенного блока кода).

Comment: @Jek_Rock а в чём проблема-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(whitespace(n))break;  
//а функция возвращает bool и проверяет содержит ли строка только табуляции/пробелы
```